# About Win32 API, how to shield the clipcursor function so that it does not take effect in the specified window handle

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Here is a window that will call the clipcursor function to lock the mouse range at a certain time. I want to mask this call process through SetWindowsHookEx, but I don't know whether it can be realized through hook.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  You need to tell us more about what you want to achieve and less about how you want to achieve it.  The obvious solution would be not to call `ClipCursor` at all, if you don't want the cursor constrained to a specific rectangle.  Just who is calling it and why?

Comment: Trying to stop it is as pointless as using it, ClipCursor doesn't actually clip the mouse cursor.  Press Ctrl+Esc to escape the mouse trap.

Comment: @HansPassant As simple as that, eh?  I guess it's an elderly API whose day is done.  Users would probably think their mouse is broken anyway.

Answer (score -4):

You cannot prevent a thread from calling `ClipCursor` by setting a [hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/hooks). It does not matter which one you choose.

Comment: Not via `SetWindowsHookEx()`, no.  Or even `SetWinEventHook()`.  But a detour could block the call on a per-thread basis. It would not be trivial to setup, though.

Comment: I'm sure there are multiple ways to intercept API calls. That doesn't change the question, and the question ultimately is: "How do I fix a bicycle tire using a potato?"